# How do I skip the installation of grub in my VPS?

Tags: vps, openvz, grub, ubuntu-10.10, ubuntu-11.04

I am upgrading Ubuntu 11.04 to Ubuntu 11.10 and it asks me to install grub, I do not want to do so as I am in  a VPS, how can  I skip installation of grub ?

[image]

If I close the session, then it shows this when I run update again

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' 
  to correct the problem.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You **want** to install grub. Without it, how are you going to boot Ubuntu after the upgrade? You shouldn't treat a virtual server any differently than a physical one, both need a bootloader to bootstrap the OS at boot.